# Experience Letter for ACS Skill Assessment (for 189 Visa) for a company which is closed

Tags: australia

One of the companies that I used to work for has been closed permanently and I face a challenge to obtain a proper reference letter from it to submit for Skill assessment. 
I have my reporting managers and other senior staff who can help me with details/letters but without company's letter head.

What are my options here? I have gained 2 years of experience in this company, and certainly leaving it out will effect my score.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having an experience letter on the company letterhead is not the only option. You can have a colleague (preferably a manager or senior employee), who was working with you, give an affidavit/undertaking stating that he was working with you and following are the duties you performed. An affidavit is a legal document that you get from a court. Along with the affidavit, you can supply salary slips (at least 3 - beginning, mid period and end) and the initial offer letter you received from the company.
This should get you through the ACS assessment without any trouble. And this is not just a workaround, ACS itself recommends this if you can't get an official letter.
Refer to page 14 of [this document](https://www.acs.org.au/content/dam/acs/acs-skills/Skills%20Assessment%20Guidelines%20for%20Applicants%20V5-6%20Aug%202018.pdf)

Comment: having salary slips for the mentioned time frames can be difficult for me in this case.